# Using CASE to properly count items with if/else logic in SQL

Tags: sql, case

Say I have a table `table` in the form:

```
| user | class |
|------|-------|
| 1    | a     |
| 1    | b     |
| 1    | b     |
| 2    | b     |
| 3    | a     |
```

There are only two classes.

I want to write a query such that we count the number of users in each class such that any user who has label `a` and `b` gets sorted into `a`, any user with just `a` gets sorted into `a` and then any user with just `b` gets into `b`. If applied to the table snippet above we would get:

```
| class | count |
|-------|-------|
| a     | 2     |
| b     | 1     |
```

Also acceptable is the transpose, like:

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| 2 | 1 |
```

My current solution involves two CTEs:

```
WITH a_users AS 
(
  SELECT
    user, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a_class
  FROM 
    table
  WHERE 
    class in ('a', 'b')
  GROUP BY 
    user
), 

labeled_users as (
SELECT 
  user, 
  CASE WHEN a_class >=1 then 'a' ELSE 'b' END as label 
FROM
  a_users
) 

SELECT 
  label, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user)
FROM 
  labeled_users;
```

Is there a (1) more efficient way to solve for this or (2) a more concise/readable solution?

Comment: Is `a` really a superset?  i.e. all people in `b` are also in `a`?

Comment: Yeah good call, edited question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want "a" for a user who has "a" at all.  A subquery is the first approach:

```
select sum(case when num_as > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_class_a,
       sum(case when num_as = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_class_b
from (select user, sum(case when class = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as num_as
      from t
      group by user
     ) t;
```

With a little trick, you can eliminate the subquery:

```
select count(distinct case when class = 'a' then user end) as num_as,
       count(distinct user) - count(distinct case when class = 'a' then user end) as num_bs
from t;
```

Comment: Hey! You forgot an underscore in `num_as` in the second line of your first code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, if `a` and `b` really are your classes.  Otherwise adjust the min/max as needed.

```
; with CTE as (
    Select user, min(class) as Class
    from Labeled_Users
    group by user)
Select Class, count(*)
from CTE
group by Class
```

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't assume that -- pretend they are two different strings

Comment: The logic should still work, you just need to choose min/max as needed for the class you want take priority.  E.g. if your classes are `priority` and `not priority` then use `max` instead of `min`, since `priority` sorts lower than `not priority`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward query to get the job done using a subquery and conditional aggregation. It should return the second version of your expected result (pivoted) :

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.minc <> x.maxc OR  x.maxc = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.minc =  x.maxc AND x.maxc = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) b
FROM ( 
    SELECT user, MAX(class) maxclass, MIN(class) minclass
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY user 
) x
```

The subquery computes the minimum and maximum class of each user. Then the outer query separatly counts users :

- `a` : users that belong to both classes or just to class `a`
- `b` : users that belong to class `b` only

This is standard SQL syntax that will work on most RDBMS (obviously, even those who do not support CTEs, such as pre-8.0 MySQL versions).

Answer (score 0):

Using `String_agg()`:

```
with usr_class as(
SELECT DISTINCT usr,
   string_agg(txt,':') as all_class
   FROM abc
   GROUP BY usr 
)
select count(usr),
    case when POSITION('a' in all_class)>0 THEN 'a'
         ELSE 'b'
    END AS CLASS 
    FROM usr_class 
    GROUP BY case when POSITION('a' in all_class)>0 THEN 'a'
             ELSE 'b'
             END;
```